# How can I extract content from a Nokia E5-00?

Tags: software-recommendation, phone, smartphone

I have been trying to find software to extract data from a Nokia E5-00. Everything Nokia-related that I've found seems to be a bit old (my model is not supported). What software can I use to extract the following from my phone:

- contacts
- messages
- media

Separate applications for each task is acceptable. The ability to do more than just extract the data would be nice but is not required. Extracting the data into a nice standard format would be very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Comment modified to answer

While you can access stored media files on your device's extended memory (Memory Card) in Ubuntu directly when you connect your device to your PC in "Mass Storage" mode, there are no Linux alternatives to Nokia PC Suite or Nokia Suite which allow you to contacts and messages.

Answer (score 1):

Install gammu, using terminal you could send, receive, read, store sms, mms, contacts.

```
apt-get install gammu*
```

search inside gammu-doc you will find examples. documentation is available on [gammu site](http://www.wammu.eu).

Note that, package `wammu` does not work with nokia e5.

if you want access internet using GSM 3G using at same time dial-up connection and gammu for handling send and receive sms together device will hang-on.

To access internet using your nokia e5 you could use wvdial package for dial-up connection.

Also see [backup using gammu](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/formats/backup.html) and some very good examples on [kalkun blog](http://back2arie.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/backupexport-your-contacts-using-gammu/)